# PHP: Notice: Array to string conversion issue caused by LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked all over for a answer to this. But all the questions asked don't seem to answer my question.

I am trying to post from a html page to a php page.
But i am receiving this notice:

> Notice: Array to string conversion ... line 41

In order to fix the issue i have stopped the page i am working on (index page) from posting to the next page, and post to the index page instead, so i can see what is going on.

**Line 41**

```
WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%".$search."%'");
```

I am using the exactly the same query, part from the variable names in another page, and it works perfectly.

I am trying to retrieve the area name from the db, which matches the postal code which is inputted by the user in the search bar on the index page, there is nothing on the index page apart from the search bar.

**Code**

```
$c_name= '';

if(isset($_POST['feed_me'])){
     $search= $_POST;

$select_pcode=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT Rest_Details.Resturant_ID, Rest_Details.City_name, Delivery_Pcode.Pcode 
 FROM Rest_Details INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
 ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Resturant_ID


echo var_dump($select_pcode);

while($row_pcode=  mysqli_fetch_array($select_pcode)){
$c_name = $row_pcode['City_name']; 

}}
```

I have never received this notice before, i am unaware how to deal with it or how to resolve the issue. Please advice

Comment: `$search= $_POST;` is wrong, should be `$search= $_POST['postcode']` or whatever name the postcode form field has

Comment: Also note that if you're feeding post variables directly into your SQL string without escaping them, you are leaving yourself **wide** open to being hacked. Look up "SQL injection attack" and make sure you understand how to avoid it before making any of your code available to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$search= $_POST;
```

That's the mistake, change it to

```html
$search= $_POST['feed_me'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are copying the whole `$_POST` array to $search and then you are trying to concatenate the array to a string.

This is the correct way:

```
if(isset($_POST['feed_me'])){
     $search= $_POST['feed_me'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$search` is `$search= $_POST;` and `$_POST` is array.

When you use it in `%$search%` here you get this error.

Implode `$_POST` with `implode('", "', $_POST)`, take only one value (`$_POST['feed_me']`) or other way make it to string.

---

Don't use direct `$_POST` in query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you for explaining also, i will try that now

Answer (score 2):

Well, `$_POST` is an array and you're passing its whole value to `$search`. Then you're using `$search` to display a message. Since `$_POST` is of type `array`, when trying to display `$search`, you would be mixing a string with an array, hence the notice.

Since you want to compare `Delivery_Pcode.Pcode`, you need to call the "Pcode" that you sent from the `$_POST` to the `$search`. Something like this:

`$search["Pcode"]`

That would bring the value you're looking for (if that's the name of the value).